# Transfer files through RDP connection

Tags: python-3.6

Trying to copy files from a remote desktop to my local. 
Here is the code that tried...

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil
import sys
import win32wnet

def netcopy(host, source, dest_dir, username=None, password=None, move=False):
    """ Copies files or directories to a remote computer. """

    wnet_connect(host, username, password)

    dest_dir = covert_unc(host, dest_dir)

    # Pad a backslash to the destination directory if not provided.
    if not dest_dir[len(dest_dir) - 1] == '\\':
        dest_dir = ''.join([dest_dir, '\\'])

    # Create the destination dir if its not there.
    if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
        os.makedirs(dest_dir)
    else:
        # Create a directory anyway if file exists so as to raise an error.
         if not os.path.isdir(dest_dir):
             os.makedirs(dest_dir)

    if move:
        shutil.move(source, dest_dir)
    else:
        shutil.copy(source, dest_dir)
```

Trying to figure out how to establish a connection and copy files over to my local.
New to python here...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an RDP client?
Is this windows linux or mac ?
Which app are you using?
Is this a code you wrote ?
Do you know what virtual channels are ?
Is NLA on?
THere is very little information you provided.
can you even connect ? Can you ping the server ?

Comment: I am using the Windows RDP app, NLA is enabled. Here is the link to the code:  [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442521-windows-network-file-transfers/)

Comment: I am using this code as reference but might have to write something from scratch